# how to transparent seas in worldGeoJSON (React leaflet) and show only one country

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geojson

I create a map with worldGeoJSON in React leaflet library

bellow is my code:

```
<LeafletMap
    center={[50, 10]}
    zoom={6}
    // minZoom={6}
    maxZoom={10}
    attributionControl={true}
    zoomControl={false}
    doubleClickZoom={true}
    scrollWheelZoom={true}
    dragging={true}
    animate={true}
    easeLinearity={0.35}
        >

        <GeoJSON
            data={worldGeoJSON}
            style={() => ({
            color: '#528cee',
            weight: 0.5,
            fillColor: "#555E6D",
            fillOpacity: 1,
        })}
        />

        <Marker position={[50, 10]}></Marker>
    </LeafletMap>
```

and this is result:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

**1. How I can change color of seas to transparent or ...**

**2. How I can display just one country**

Comment: Someone answered your second question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70945771/how-to-show-only-one-country-using-react-leaflet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the first question:
add

```
background: transparent;
```

to

```
.leaflet-container
```