# How to show only one country using react leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using react-leaflet in one of my projects and I want to show only one country and delete the rest or hide.

Someone has solved this problem but unfortunately it's not for React. Do you know how to turn this into a react code or use it in a react project?

[LeafletJs only show one country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643086/leafletjs-only-show-one-country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the library and import it:

```
import "leaflet-boundary-canvas";
```

After retrieving the map instance create a `useEffect` that will fetch the example's `geojson` having the map in the dependency array. Copy paste the code. The only difference here is that you have to use `L.TileLayer.boundaryCanvas` instead of `new L.TileLayer.BoundaryCanvas` to initialize the plugin

```
...
const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    const fetchGeoJSON = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://cdn.rawgit.com/johan/world.geo.json/34c96bba/countries/GBR.geo.json"
      );
      const geoJSON = await response.json();
      const osm = L.TileLayer.boundaryCanvas(
        "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        {
          boundary: geoJSON,
          attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, UK shape <a href="https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json">johan/word.geo.json</a>'
        }
      );
      map.addLayer(osm);
      const ukLayer = L.geoJSON(geoJSON);
      map.fitBounds(ukLayer.getBounds());
    };

    fetchGeoJSON();
  }, [map]);

return (
    <MapContainer
      ...
      whenCreated={setMap}
    />
  );
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v3-how-to-show-only-one-country-using-react-leaflet-n9ydm?file=/src/Map.jsx:334-1124)

Answer (score 0):

It's been 2 years but hope this helps, at least, it worked for me. If you have the country boundaries GeoJSON (Multipolygon Feature). You may use @turf

```
    import { featureEach, difference, buffer } from '@turf/turf';

const getInverseFeature = (featureCollection, distance) => {
  // Create a bounding box for the entire world

  let invertedPolygon;

  // Loop through each feature in the FeatureCollection
  featureEach(featureCollection, (feature) => {
    // Buffer the feature polygon slightly to ensure it covers the boundaries
    const bufferedFeature = buffer(feature, 40, { units: 'kilometers' }); //You may use distance instead of 40 km, I just hard coded the 40 km to show Sea Border lines of Country which was added by Openstreet map

    // Convert the buffered feature to a GeoJSON polygon
    const featurePolygon = bufferedFeature;

    // If invertedPolygon already exists, subtract the current feature polygon from it
    if (invertedPolygon) {
      invertedPolygon = difference(invertedPolygon, featurePolygon);
    } else {
      // Otherwise, initialize invertedPolygon with the first feature polygon
      invertedPolygon = featurePolygon;
    }
  });

  // Subtract the inverted polygon from the world bounding box
  const worldPolygon = {
    type: 'Polygon',
    coordinates: [
      [
        [-180, -90],
        [180, -90],
        [180, 90],
        [-180, 90],
        [-180, -90],
      ],
    ],
  };

  return difference(worldPolygon, invertedPolygon);
};
```

With the help of function you can get inverse feature and (In React I used the GeoJSON component)

```
 <GeoJSON
      data={outterBounds}
      pathOptions={{
        color: mapChange ? '#163a4a' : '#aad3df',
        // weight: 2.5,
        lineCap: 'round',
        fill: true,
        fillOpacity: 0.98,
      }}
    />
```

But this is important to know, you shouldn't use the function in Frontend, because it is a very slow function and will freeze the brower. To use the inverse feature you may use one of the following options.

1- Generate Inverse Feature in Backend and return the result from backend to frontend (By the way, the FeatureCollection at function is the Feature Collection of the Country Coastline (Borderlines of the country))

2- You may use it at frontend just once, console log the Reverse Feature to DevTools console, copy the object and create a country outter bounds constant and import it to the file which you will generate the map and use GeoJSON.

3- Use the second option, add copied object to DB and fetch it from DB (again you will get the data from Backend but this time you do not need to use the above function calculation again and again.

Result from the above (I used 2nd option by the way) :

[image]